# Can we create the customize report after publish?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sql-server-data-tools, database-project

I am creating database project in visual studio 2013.After publish visual studio is creating report. Can we create the customize report after publish database on Dev/QA server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

`sqlpackage.exe /Action:DeployReport /SourceFile:PATHTODACPAC.dacpac /TargetServerName:ServerName /TargetDatabaseName:DatabaseName /OutputPath:c:\PathToReport.xml`

Replace:

- PATHTODACPAC.dac with the path to the dacpac
- ServerName with the server name
- DatabaseName with the database name
- C:\PathToReport.xml with the path of the file you want the output in

sqlpackage.exe will be in one of these locations:

- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DAC\bin
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DAC\bin

this will generate a deployment report. For all the possible parameters for sqlpackage.exe see:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550080(v=vs.103).aspx

ed

Comment: Given msdn link is not working.

Currently I am publishing my database through visual studio. Also I am able view the report. but I need more in details report.

I have never uses any command to do any operations. Please tell me how execute this command.

Comment: so you have the report but you want it to show something different?

Comment: I want to in details report. 
** Following report is generated : ** Highlights
     Tables that will be rebuilt
       None
     Clustered indexes that will be dropped
       None
     Clustered indexes that will be created
       None
     Possible data issues
       None

** User actions
     Alter
       [dbo].[Employee] (Table)

** Supporting actions
     Refresh
       [dbo].[TestView] (View)

If this deployment is executed, changes to [dbo].[Employee] might introduce run-time errors in [dbo].[TestViewWithFullName].
**

Comment: ok you want what you get when you click "View Highlights" in the publish results window! - I have updated the answer with the command line arguements for sqlpackage.exe which will give you an xml report of basically the same thing

Comment: Thanks Ed Elliott. It works perfectly as you said. But I need some different approach Like automated build or publish through visual studio it self. Is any option present there to detail review.

Comment: create a batch file or powershell script to call it :)